# Intermediate layer between DataEntities and Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I was reading this tutorial for MVC3 with Linq to Entities using Model First.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

A quote from the article states

> Our controllers will use the BlogDataEntities to retrieve data for us.
>   In a more advanced application, you should separate logic further and
>   would not be working with the BlogDataEntities directly from the
>   controller.

What is the general structure of this other layer between the entities and Controller in an MVC application? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a bastardized ViewModel (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) which contains the business logic, can fetch/save from EF and is what the view is bound to. The controller doesn't do much but instantiate the viewmodel and depending on the controller action, call a method within the view model.

Some people might break that up even further and have a full blown ViewModel which has no logic in it,just data. A business layer with all of the logic and the ability to move data from EF to the ViewModel and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

In the article "BlogDataEntities" is not the name for some specific entity classes (what the name suggests) but the name of the DbContext.

I guess it means that you would try to hide that you work with EF by not instantiating the DbContext, but by using a repository-implementation like this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff707264#_Toc261428890